# How to convince GHC that this pattern synonym is complete?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm using **GHC 9.0.1**. I have this typeclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Kind

type Has :: ((Type -> Type) -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Constraint
class Has r_ m env | env -> m where
  dep :: env -> r_ m
```

And this (admittedly weird) rank-2 function:

```
makeCaller :: forall env m . env -> forall r_ x. Has r_ m env => (r_ m -> x) -> x
makeCaller env = \f -> f (dep env)
```

which I use as a view pattern. I want to hide the use of the view pattern behind this [pattern synonym](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html):

```
pattern Call :: forall env m . (forall r_ x. Has r_ m env => (r_ m -> x) -> x) -> env
pattern Call env <- (makeCaller -> env)
```

Which actually works fine, except for one thing: in monadic contexts, it
requires a `MonadFail` constraint from the monad. I would like to remove the
need for `MonadFail` by marking the pattern synonym as [`COMPLETE`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#complete-pragma):

```
{-# COMPLETE Call #-}
```

Alas, it doesn't work:

```
* A type signature must be provided for a set of polymorphic pattern synonyms.
* In {-# COMPLETE Call #-}
```

I don't know what signature should be given in the pragma. Putting the whole `forall env m . (forall r_ x. Has r_ m env => (r_ m -> x) -> x) -> env` gives a parse error.

Is there a way to mark the pattern synonym as `COMPLETE`?

Comment: I think there's not much to answer here, this is just _not supported_. You could make a GHC feature request out of it, however you should be clear that what you're doing is pretty much abuse of `PatternSynonyms` to begin with.

Comment: This GHC ticket appears to be related: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/19160

Comment: This ticket is related as well: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/15681

Comment: I don't have this problem any more with GHC 9.2.4.